# Hide programmatically created UIButton for tag

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

Currently I have 14 buttons being created programmatically using a for loop, code below:

```
int buttonCount = 14;
for (int i=0; i< buttonCount; i++) {             
    
//Create titleString from array object
    NSString *stringFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayForRound objectAtIndex:i]];
        

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        
        [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(buttonSelected:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        [button setTitle:stringFromInt forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"helvetica" size:19];
        button.tag = i;
        
        [self.view addSubview:button];
}
```

This works great to create the buttons, I can then populate the Answer Box with the value of the selected button:

```
-(void)buttonSelected: (UIButton *)sender
{
[_buttonOne setTitle:sender.titleLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

However after the button has been populated I would like to remove it from the screen. If i call button.hidden it simply hides the last button that was programmatically created. I am aware of button.tag and have tried to use this, but it feels like I almost need to do something like:

```
//Hide button for tag (i know this is incorrect syntax)
button for buttonTag: 3 setHidden;
```

Is there something similar or a way of doing this?

#### Update

The button that I am trying to hide is the one that was created programatically. So I want _buttonOne to take on the title of the create button (lets call that letterButton), and then hide letterButton from the view,

```
UIButton *yourBtn = (UIButton *)[self.button viewWithTag:3];
[yourBtn setHidden:YES];
(code posted by Oh Seung Kwon)
```

This code work perfectly but it hides the wrong set of buttons. (Hides _buttonOne and not letterButton).

I wonder if it would not be better to create the 12 buttons in nib and name them manually...There will never be more or less that 12.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When your button is tapped, you can set the `hidden` property on the action method's `sender` argument, which is the button that actually got tapped. This will hide the button which was tapped.

```
- (void)buttonSelected:(UIButton *)sender {
   [_buttonOne setTitle:sender.titleLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [sender setHidden:YES];
}
```

If you meant to retrieve the button with the tag of `3`, you can use this code instead:

```
[[self.view viewWithTag:3] setHidden:YES];
```

*I don't recommend that you use the `tag` property - you should use Interface Builder and an `IBOutletCollection` instead.*

Comment: Hey Jacob, thanks for the reply, I am having a little trouble with implementing an IBOutletCollection using the for loop. Could you please give me a bit more information on that or should I start another question? thanks again

Comment: I ended up using self.view tag, The problem I was getting was the tag's were interfering amongst buttons, so i simply set the button.tag  to be i+10. This seemed to clear everything up, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
UIButton *yourBtn = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:3];
[yourBtn setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: Hey Oh, this seems to be throwing some errors about, It is also removing the wrong button, so thanks for the answer but I think I will try using an Outlet Collection. T

Comment: My apologise, this code does work! But it is not quite right for what im trying to achieve, I have updated my question to reflect this

Comment: Sorry, I just see your response now.

Comment: I think you got better answer. Regards

Answer (score 1):

You could get the view by tag use this message.

```
[self.view viewWithTag:3];
```

We always specific tag by macro just like

```
#define kFirstButtonTag (100)
```

or use

```
#define kButtonBeginTag (100)
```

Then use the macro to get tag.

And in a special number - Case 0, 1 or 2 is always use, begin your tag in a special number could avoid some problems