# How to remove Button from View

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a five button check this link,
[How to remove duplicate buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090646/how-to-remove-duplicate-buttons)

i tried this code:

```
oneBtn1.hidden = YES;
```

Problem is: I created  a buttons with same name but different tag. It is possible to remove button comparing tag or any other way to solve these problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your relevant code and point out what you need help with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214502/hide-programmatically-created-uibutton-for-tag try this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to remove the button with a particular tag, then use

```
[(UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:TAG_ID]  removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 1):

the name you used to create button, only point to the last one button, so, it only remove one button. other buttons as subviews of [self.view], has no var point to.

use

```
[self.view viewWithTag:theTag]
```

to get the button with tag, then operate on it.